# Вывод даты в Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Создал TodDo list по туториалу. Хочу сделать дополнительное поле ввода даты, рядом с полем ввода задания, чтобы при отображении задания рядышком отображалась выбранная дата, или сегодняшняя, если ничего не введено в поле даты.(рисунок прикладываю, хочу чтобы напротив "Do homework" была выведена дата, которую записали в инпут по by) Не могу разобраться с алгоритмом как и что делать: нужно создать класс Date, после этого добавить в метод, где создается задание? или есть какой то более простой способ? Попытался написать сам - не вышло, вот ссылка на гитхаб. 
[гитхаб](https://github.com/DYalo/ToDo-List/blob/master/src/app/services/todo.service.ts)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В какой момент времени вы хотите дату выводить? При отображении списка или при создании нового задания?

Comment: @SergeyRogachev я хочу вводить дату после ввода задания и чтобы она отображалась рядом с заданием при его выводе в списке

Comment: [В этой строке](https://github.com/DYalo/ToDo-List/blob/master/src/app/components/todo-input/todo-input.component.ts#L14) у вас инициализация текстового поля. В следующей строке просто ``this.todoDate = new Date();``

Comment: @SergeyRogachev если я задам эту строку, то дата будет появляться в в поле ввода, а не рядом с заданием в листе.

Comment: А вы где хотите?

Comment: Рядом с самим заданием в листе

1. Сделать уроки -----------------------02.08.2016

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так в разметке:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Задача:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control " type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.text">                
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Время:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control " type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.date">                
    </div>
</div>
```

Todo сделайте так:

```
export class Todo {
   id: number;
   text: string;
   date: string;

   constructor(id: number, text: string, date: string) {
       this.id = id;
       this.text = text;
       this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Вывод сделайте примерно так:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <span [textContent]="item.text"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <span [textContent]="item.date"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"> Удалить </button>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем понял, что это, зачем вы сделали кнопку. я пытаюсь сделать просто отображение введенной даты рядом с введенным текстом

Comment: Где? В каком файле. Укажите точнее.

Comment: исправил вопрос, спасибо